# how to transpose multiple set of column into rows

Tags: text-processing

Can we transpose multiple set of values into rows in linux.

Below is the sample data i have ..

```
UID,UNAME,UKEY,UFROMDATE,UTODATE,UL,ULID,UF,UFID
"1","abc","12344321","2019-01-01","2019-01-10","1","1A","X1","XA"
"2","abc","12344322","2019-02-01","2019-02-10","2","2A","X2","XB"
```

Can we transporse above data into below format

```
UID,UNAME,UKEY,UFROMDATE,UTODATE,ColVal,ID,ColName
"1","abc","12344321","2019-01-01","2019-01-10","1","1A",UL
"1","abc","12344321","2019-01-01","2019-01-10","X1","XA",UF
"2","abc","12344322","2019-02-01","2019-02-10","2","2A",UL
"2","abc","12344322","2019-02-01","2019-02-10","X2","XB",UF
```

Please help me with any suggestion..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't have any commas inside the quoted strings, we can use awk with the field separators set to comma. Then just manually printing the header line and for each line the columns 1 to 7 and then 1-5,8-9:

```
$ awk -F, -vOFS=, 'NR == 1 {print "UID,UNAME,UKEY,UFROMDATE,UTODATE,ColVal,ID,ColName"}; 
    NR != 1 {print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, "UL"; 
             print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $8, $9, "UF"; }' < file.txt
UID,UNAME,UKEY,UFROMDATE,UTODATE,ColVal,ID,ColName
"1","abc","12344321","2019-01-01","2019-01-10","1","1A",UL
"1","abc","12344321","2019-01-01","2019-01-10","X1","XA",UF
"2","abc","12344322","2019-02-01","2019-02-10","2","2A",UL
"2","abc","12344322","2019-02-01","2019-02-10","X2","XB",UF
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. In future , i got some more 2 new columns to transpose , its like i need to add one more line again  like  "  print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $10, $11, "XX" --- am i right ?

Comment: I have commas inside the quoted string as well, will there be any way ?

Comment: @Arya, I can't remember if there was a simple way to deal with quoted strings in awk. There might be something about that on the site (or maybe someone else will show to write an answer here). If you have more than a few columns to spread out, it might call for a loop. In any case, I suggest you [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/525954/edit) your question to include those details!

Comment: @ikkachu.. As per the suggestion i have edited question. Always set of combination will be same i will have always set of 2 columns, in future i may need to add few more columns..Can you help me with suggestion

Comment: @ikkachu.. Please help me how can i implement above part in a loop..

Comment: Actually this solution helped me a lot ( other than loop ) . So thats why i marked it as answer. But as you have provided your time to help me. i  accepted answer,

Answer (score 0):

Something more dirty with sed

```
$ echo "UID,UNAME,UKEY,UFROMDATE,UTODATE,ColVal,ID,ColName" && sed -E '1d; s|"([0-9]+",.+),("[0-9]","[0-9][A-Z]"),("X[0-9]","X[A-Z]")$|\1,\2,UL\n\1,\3,UF|' file.txt
```

result

```
UID,UNAME,UKEY,UFROMDATE,UTODATE,ColVal,ID,ColName
1","abc","12344321","2019-01-01","2019-01-10","1","1A",UL
1","abc","12344321","2019-01-01","2019-01-10","X1","XA",UF
2","abc","12344322","2019-02-01","2019-02-10","2","2A",UL
2","abc","12344322","2019-02-01","2019-02-10","X2","XB",UF
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply.. In future , i got some more 2 new columns to transpose , its like i need to add one more syntax like  ""   \1,\4,XX  "" .. am i right ?

Comment: Well, with SED you have to deal with parenthesis and then add \1 \2 \3 \x depending the position of the parenthesis. But in this case I would say the AWK solution is probably easier and cleaner

Comment: Thanks... How can we implement loop by using Awk ...?